# Will Photoshop CS version 8.0 work if I update from Tiger to Leopard?

Tags: leopard, powerpc, adobe-photoshop, ibook

I have just baught an Iphone and I have to upgrade my itunes, but it says my operating system is too old. I have an Ibook G4 10.4.11 with a 1.42 GHz PowerPC G4 processor. The support team are sending me out a disc to install Leopard operating system. However, I am worried that once I install it I may not be able to run Photoshop CS version 8.0. Will this be an issue, as I use it everyday. If so, I am thinking of returning the iphone.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. I heard that there maybe issues with intel based macs, but I think mine is PowerPC...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, 8.0 runs even in Snow Leopard.

Also:  look in the Help menu and see if there is a "Deactivate" choice.  (I think 8.0 is before that started, actually.)  If so, then you should deactivate Photoshop, install the new OS, then activate it again.

Comment: Thank you :), is Snow Leopard the next one up from Leopard? Still a little uneasy about upgrading from Tiger as I'm wondering if it may effect any of my other programs that all run fine in Tiger. Is it something to be concerned about? Can you always go back to Tiger if Leopard has issues? Thank you for reading :)

Comment: @Cherie If you make a backup of your Mac's hard drive, you can easily revert to Tiger if you need to. I'd recommend [SuperDuper!](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html) or [Carbon Copy Cloner](http://www.bombich.com/) to do this, so you can simply reboot into your Tiger backup if you need to.